# CorelDraw: problems converting to curves text with embedded graphics

Tags: vector, page-layout, corel-draw, raster

In CorelDraw it is possible to insert arbitrary graphics (raster or vector) right into line of text by copy-pasting object into it.

It is useful sometimes since this embedded object will be scaled along with the text, follow the path line of text is attached to, etc. It would generally work as a character of a font.

BUT. When you try to print resulting work or use "Convert to curves" operation, embedded object would not be rendered, it will be replaced by blank space and the program will give you warning message.

So, is there a way to convert such document to curves?

Comment: What does the warning message say?

Comment: Do you have large texts inserted with a single image?

Answer (score 1):

In CorelDraw x7 when you convert the text into curve you lose the clipping content, or it seems like you lose it ... the truth is you didn't lose it but it re-position itself according to the new created object .. I belief it's a bug in CorelDraw ... but after converting text into curves and if you click `edit clipping content` again you will retrieve the raster content somewhere in your document.

Answer (score 0):

Rather workaround than a solution, since I don't use Corel, but it should work in any program since it's low-tech ;):

I'd copy inserted graphics, change the text to outlines, and paste objects from clipboard exactly into their previous places. I'm sure Corel have an option to paste object directly into position the object was copied/cut from. Since you say that objects are replaced in text by blank spaces, this should work right on.

The other thing is – do you really need to create outlines?

Comment: Outlines is diferent to curves, you can have a converted to curves text and also asign an outline. :)

Comment: I meant “outlines”, like “glyph shape «outlined» by curves”, not “shape «outlined» by a line of such and such color and thickness” :}